# Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-deployment, azure-ad-b2c, app-secret

We are trying to create secrets for applications in b2c tenant from powershell.

After searching a lot, came across these commands that are working fine for normal applications.

```
$StartDate = Get-Date
$EndDate = $StartDate.AddYears(5)
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -CustomKeyIdentifier b2csecret -ObjectId 6133a24a-2cc7-4b47-901c-2e2c67b0bed6 -EndDate $EndDate
```

But this fails for applications of Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows) type.

```
    New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential : Error occurred while executing SetApplication
    Code: Request_BadRequest
    Message: Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.
    RequestId: 9630857f-6d32-4788-8637-0a15967beb22
    DateTimeStamp: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 13:22:19 GMT
    HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
    HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
    HttpResponseStatus: Completed
    At line:3 char:1
    + New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -CustomKeyIdentifier b2csecr ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential], ApiException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Graph.PowerShell.Custom.NewAzureADA
pplicationPasswordCredential
```

Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version means is there no way? How to create secrets in b2c application of `Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)` type programmatically from powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one **B2C application** with same account type as you like below:

[image]

When I ran same commands as you to create client secret, I got **same error** like this:

```
$StartDate = Get-Date
$EndDate = $StartDate.AddYears(5)
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -CustomKeyIdentifier b2csecret -ObjectId 210903f0-f7e4-4bd8-9de8-61b419f99ea7 -EndDate $EndDate
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below commands by connecting to **Microsoft Graph** like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

$params = @{
    PasswordCredential = @{
        DisplayName = "b2csecret"
    }
}

Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId <b2cObjectID> -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **client secret** created successfully in B2C application like below:

[image]